# How to paginate objects from a relationship

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

How can i return this same query with pagination from the relacted produtos with categoria?

My `Model DB`:

[image: Model DataBase]

Config `Model Eloquent categoria`:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Categoria extends ModelDefault
{
    protected $table = 'categoria';

    public function produtos()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Produto', 'categoria_produto', 'categoria_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Config `Model Eloquent produto`:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Produto extends ModelDefault
{
    protected $table = 'produto';

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Categoria', 'categoria_produto', 'produto_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProdutoImagem','produto_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

My query to get `produtos` from `categoria`:

```
$produtosPorCategoria = Categoria::with(['produtos.images.image'])
        ->where('slug', $categoria_slug)
        ->ativo()
        ->first();
    dd($produtosPorCategoria);
```

Here you can see a printscreen from my returned array:

[image]

Comment: By "paginate" do you mean to limit the amount that the relationship will bring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you need. you should try this

```
$produtosPorCategoria = Categoria::with(['produtos.images.image'])
    ->where('slug', $categoria_slug)
    ->ativo()
    ->first();
```

Should be

```
$produtosPorCategoria = Categoria::with(['produtos.images.image'])
    ->where('slug', $categoria_slug)
    ->ativo()
    ->first();

$produtosPorCategoria = $produtosPorCategoria->produtos()->paginate(5);
```